# Sum split values from HTML form, use as data for Google scatter chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, google-visualization

I am creating an online quiz and want be able to plot the score on a chart.

I am attempting to add all the comma separated values in the checked radio buttons of a form in such a way that the result is also a comma separated value, however I am unsure how to do this.

**Example:**

```
2,2 + -2,2 + 1,-1 = 1,3
```

I then want to insert the resulting number into the Google Visualisation API to draw a chart on the same page, preferably updated as each radio button is checked.

**Sample form code:**

```
<form>

<input type="radio" name="q1" class="option" value="2,-2" /> 
<input type="radio" name="q1" class="option" value="1,-1" /> 
<input type="radio" name="q1" class="option" value="0,0" /> 
<input type="radio" name="q1" class="option" value="-1,1" /> 
<input type="radio" name="q1" class="option" value="-2,2" />

<input type="radio" name="q2" class="option" value="2,-2" /> 
<input type="radio" name="q2" class="option" value="1,-1" /> 
<input type="radio" name="q2" class="option" value="0,0" /> 
<input type="radio" name="q2" class="option" value="-1,1" /> 
<input type="radio" name="q2" class="option" value="-2,2" />

</form>
```

**Google Visualisation API:**

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

    ['',''],

    [0,0]

  ]);

var options = {
  hAxis: {minValue: -94, maxValue: 94, gridlines: {count:0}},
  vAxis: {minValue: -94, maxValue: 94, gridlines: {count:0}},
  legend: 'none',
  colors: ['#000000'],
  width: 500,
  height: 500
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

I have been looking for a way to accomplish this however so far none of the solutions I have found are suitable. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9obrcwty/4/) example to show you how to sum comma separated values dinamically. Once you get the values you can plot the result with Google Visualization API.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var radios = $('input[type=radio]');

  var evalResult = function(){

    var sum1 = 0;
    var sum2 = 0;

    var q1 = $("input[type=radio][name=q1]:checked").val();
    var q2 = $("input[type=radio][name=q2]:checked").val();

    var values_q1 = q1.split(',');
    var values_q2 = q2.split(',');

    sum1 = parseInt(values_q1[0]) + parseInt(values_q1[0]);
    sum2 = parseInt(values_q1[1]) + parseInt(values_q2[1]);

    $(".expression").html(q1+" + "+ q2 + " = "+ sum1 + ","+sum2);
  }

  evalResult();
  radios.change(evalResult);

});
```

**EDIT**

You can generalize the procedure over *n* questions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var radios = $('input[type=radio]');

  var evalResult = function(){

    var numQuestions = 80;
    var sum1 = 0;
    var sum2 = 0;

    var expr_str = '';
    for(var i = 1; i <= numQuestions; i++){
      var q = $("input[type=radio][name=q"+i+"]:checked").val();
      var value = q.split(',');
      sum_1 += parseInt(value[0]);
      sum_2 += parseInt(value[1]);
      expr_str += (i <= numQuestions) ? q + " + " : q + " = ";
    }

    $(".expression").html(expr_str);
  }

  evalResult();
  radios.change(evalResult);

});
```

Comment: This works, thanks, however I'm not sure it's the most efficient way to do it since I have 80 questions in the quiz.

Comment: Sure, but the code is meant to be as simple as possible so that everyone can understand it. Obviously you can choose to send data to Google Visualization API once all the questions are checked.

Comment: Your edit simplifies things a lot, thanks for that. I had an idea it was something along those lines but I'm still a newbie at Javascript/jQuery. As for sending the data to the Visualisation API, I'm a bit stumped. Tried a few things suggested by the documentation, and a few that weren't, but nothing seems to work. I've probably missed something really simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think following code should do the job

```js
var totalVal = $(':checked')
  .map(function() { return $(this).val(); })
  .toArray()
  .reduce(function(sum, val) {
    var splitVal = val.split(',');
    sum[0] = sum[0] + parseInt(splitVal[0], 10);
    sum[1] = sum[1] + parseInt(splitVal[1], 10);
    return sum;
  }, [0, 0]);

console.log(totalVal)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
<form>

  <input checked type="radio" name="q1" class="option" value="2,-2" />
  <input type="radio" name="q1" class="option" value="1,-1" />
  <input type="radio" name="q1" class="option" value="0,0" />
  <input type="radio" name="q1" class="option" value="-1,1" />
  <input type="radio" name="q1" class="option" value="-2,2" />

  <input type="radio" name="q2" class="option" value="2,-2" />
  <input checked type="radio" name="q2" class="option" value="1,-1" />
  <input type="radio" name="q2" class="option" value="0,0" />
  <input type="radio" name="q2" class="option" value="-1,1" />
  <input type="radio" name="q2" class="option" value="-2,2" />

</form>
```